# Python calling map() with 'self'

Tags: python, self

I have this function (includes description):

```
def deep_list(x):
    """fully copies trees of tuples to a tree of lists.
    deep_list( (1,2,(3,4)) ) returns [1,2,[3,4]]"""
    if type(x)!=type( () ):
        return x
    return map(deep_list,x)
```

I would like to insert that function into a functions class I've made, so I need to add `self` to the function arguments at the beginning.

My problem is this:
How do I insert in the right way `self` to the 'map' function in the end of the `deep_list`?

Comment: What is a "functions class"? Please tell me you're not collecting functions into a class as static methods?

Comment: collecting as static methods inside class. the guy below helped thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends how `x` relates to your class.

One way is to make the function a static method. This is probably the least likely

```
@staticmethod
def deep_list(x):
    """fully copies trees of tuples to a tree of lists.
       deep_list( (1,2,(3,4)) ) returns [1,2,[3,4]]"""
    if type(x)!=type( () ):
        return x
    return map(deep_list,x)
```

If you mean to operate on an attribute, then do it this way

```
def deep_list(self):
    """fully copies trees of tuples to a tree of lists.
       deep_list( (1,2,(3,4)) ) returns [1,2,[3,4]]"""
    if type(self.x)!=type( () ):
        return self.x
    return map(deep_list, self.x)
```

Finally, if you are subclassing `list` or making a sequence like class, you may just use `self`

```
def deep_list(self):
    """fully copies trees of tuples to a tree of lists.
       deep_list( (1,2,(3,4)) ) returns [1,2,[3,4]]"""
    if type(self)!=type( () ):
        return self
    return map(deep_list, self)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking, but if you map a bound method, the self will already be included:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def func(self, x):
...         return x + 2
>>> f = Foo()
>>> map(f.func, [1, 2, 3])
[3, 4, 5]
```